# "How are your first impressions?" vs "What are your first impressions?"

Tags: grammar, usage

Can either of these sentences be used?

> **"How are your first impressions of this city?"**
>
> **"What are your first impressions of this city?"**

Also, can I say either of these sentences?

> **"My first impressions of this city are good."**
>
> **"My first impressions of this city are that this is a good city."**

Context: Let's say I visited a city for the first time with a friend of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Personally as a native English speaker, I would use **“What are your first impressions of this city?”** I’ve never heard anyone use **“How are your first impressions of this city?”** before.

Both **“My first impressions of this city are good.”** and **“My first impressions of this city are that this is a good city.”** can be used.

Comment: +1 "***What*** are your *(first)* impressions of this city?" is the standard question.